# Fetching JSON response to Angular Input field?

Tags: angular, angular6

When JSON response returns from the server? how to fetch those return data to Text Boxes in Angular 6?

As Requested i have attached the code below! pls kindly look into it!

Component.html

```
<app-modal-basic #modalDefault>
    <div class="app-modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title"> {{ brandname }} Details</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close basic-close" (click)="modalDefault.hide()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-body">
      <div class="container">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="brand" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Brand ID</label>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{brand.brandId}}" id="brand" minlength="3" readonly>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="brand" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Brand</label>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" name="brandname" value="{{brand.brand}}" class="form-control" id="brand" minlength="3" >
              </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" (click)="modalDefault.hide()">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light ">Update</button>

    </div>
  </app-modal-basic>
```

TS file

```
 findybrandid(brandid: number) {

    this.brandService.getbrandid(brandid)
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data),
          error =>  console.log(error));   
 }
```

[I have given the output and my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqJdR.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried already, please provide code.

Comment: I would recommend to visit angular docs, display data section https://v6.angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: i have attached the code

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE:

On your code do not is assigned the service return value to your brand object.

```
 findybrandid(brandid: number) {

  this.brandService.getbrandid(brandid).subscribe(
    data => this.brand = data, // like this
    error =>  console.log(error));   
}
```

Please,
provide some code for a better understanding.
anyway, follow my explanation.

I suppose you will use a service for retrieving the API data.
In service you have something like this:

```
getClient(): Observable<Cliente> {
   return this.http.get<Cliente>(`${this.url}/client/1`)
}
```

This method return an Observable object for the component. In componente you do something like this:

```
getClient() {
this.clienteService.getClient().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.cliente = res; // add service return to your attribute      
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  }
)}
```

This way you can get the service response data and assign to Text Boxes:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{cliente.name}}" />
```

[This guide](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) explain in details how to display data in Angular.